# Why to Implement Asynchronous Service if Asynchronous Proxies on client does the exact same thing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, asynchronous

Initially I have my Service Contract :

```
 [ServiceContract]
    interface IDataRetrieve
    {            
       [OperationContract]
       List<OrderDetails> GetOrderDetails(string FilterValue);
    }
```

And Implemented the Service as :

```
public List<OrderDetails> GetOrderDetails(string filterValue)
        {
            //My Operation
        }
```

Now After following the [article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx) , I updated my Service Contract

```
 [ServiceContract]

interface IDataRetrieve
{
    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetOrderDetails(string filterValue, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    List<OrderDetails> EndGetOrderDetails(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

And the Implementation:

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginGetOrderDetails(string filterValue, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
        {
            this.FilterValue = filterValue;
            var task = Task<List<OrderDetails>>.Factory.StartNew(this.WorkerFunction, asyncState);

            return task.ContinueWith(res => callback(task));
        }

public List<OrderDetails> EndGetOrderDetails(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            return ((Task<List<OrderDetails>>)result).Result;
        }
  public List<OrderDetails> WorkerFunction(object state)
        {
           //My Operation
        }
```

But While using both the implementation in ASP.NET observed the same result being returned in same fashion.

So , Why should I take the extra step to implement asynchronously while the same can be accomplished just by creating proxies in client side? I think  using Task is not the only benefit here?

Am I missing something important !!

Comment: Do you really believe the contention in terms of resources, in terms of a client/server system, are on the *client* side? Should the server spend time dumbly waiting for things to happen, or should it maybe be servicing requests from *other* clients?

Answer (score 0):

Over the past few years, our team has received a good deal of sound WCF assistance from Wenlong Dong’s blog, so we generally value his thoughts.  As such, I recommend the following article on WCF asynchronous programming.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/02/09/scale-wcf-application-better-with-asynchronous-programming.aspx

"For blocking calls such as I/O operations or remote calls, you should always thinking about using asynchronous patterns. In those cases, you would be able to reduce number of threads used in the system while waiting for operations to complete. Here are a few cases where you would like to use asynchronous patterns:

1. A WCF **service** operation is waiting for a database operation
   to complete.
2. A WCF **service** operation calls into another WCF client proxy of a backend WCF service.
3. A UI thread waits for data from WCF **client** calls."

Regards,

Comment: How is this Different from creating just the WCF Asynchronous proxies while adding the Service Reference . That way I don't need to go for over head of implementing and remembering all the specification of Async Patter on Service Side

Comment: I tend to see the two asynchronous options (client-side or server-side) as solutions to two different issues. As Wenlong,s case list shows, if the server is waiting on long running tasks, then an async service solution may be needed to free up threads that would otherwise be waiting.  If on the other hand, the service responds quickly with responses, then server side async implementation would not be needed.  In either case, if the client does not want to wait for the service, the client has the option of using the async service reference call.